# settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value in postgres while installing Nadine

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to install Nadine and while running `./manage.py` migrate command i am getting the error:

`raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details`.

Answer (score 0):

Nadine's [quickstart docs](https://nadine.readthedocs.io/en/master/quickstart.html) are *very* superficial and users seem to be expected to have a baseline understanding of Django.

Nadine comes with a [base settings file](https://github.com/nadineproject/nadine/blob/master/nadine/settings/base.py), providing defaults where they make sense. However, database settings cannot be assumed by the developers, hence this parameter is just an [empty dict in the base settings](https://github.com/nadineproject/nadine/blob/master/nadine/settings/base.py#L29). 
You are expected to provide a `local_settings.py` file, to overwrite the `base.py`'s defaults where required.

In the `nadine.settings` package, you'll find a [`local_settings.example.py`](https://github.com/nadineproject/nadine/blob/master/nadine/settings/local_settings.example.py) file. This file contains settings that you will have to adjust for your local Nadine installation. Either rename the existing example file to `local_settings.py`, or make a copy of the example file with that name, and adjust the parameters to suit your needs. The resulting file must be located in the same path as the example file.

Also, have a look at [Django's settings documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/) for more information about the usage of different settings, e.g. the [SECRET_KEY](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#secret-key), as well as important notes and warnings.

Comment: Thanks @shmee i have resolved my issue with the help of your answer. But now i am facing another issue that is while running server - **./manage.py runserver** my project is running but in the browser it's only showing the html and text but not the images (in nadine project)